# как выглядел синтаксис пайтон 1х?

Tags: python

прив и мне тут стало интересно как выглядел синтаксис пайтон 1х
вот пайтон 3х:

```
print("у")
```

вот пайтон 2х:

```
print"у"
```

а вот как выглядел пайтон 1х?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что эта информация доступна на официальном сайте Python и видна в документации к нему. Нет смысла иметь здесь такой общий вопрос.

Comment: @void любая информация про Python доступна на официальном сайте Python. Давайте теперь все вопросы по питону закрывать?

Comment: @andreymal согласен

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что эта информация доступна на официальном сайте Python и видна в документации к нему. Нет смысла иметь здесь такой общий вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

[python.org/download/releases/1.6.1](http://python.org/download/releases/1.6.1)

Видимо такой же как и во второй

`print 's'`

Comment: но чем они отличаются

Comment: @yarik, ваш вопрос был какой он, а не чем он отличается. Вообще он практически не отличается, разве что функции были другие и некоторых небыло

Answer (score 2):

Примеры из документации python 1.6

```
x = 10 * 3.14
y = 200*200
s = 'The value of x is ' + `x` + ', and y is ' + `y` + '...'
print s
# Reverse quotes work on other types besides numbers:
p = [x, y]
ps = repr(p)
print ps
# Converting a string adds string quotes and backslashes:
hello = 'hello, world\n'
hellos = `hello`
print hellos
```

И еще один пример.

```
print 'The value of PI is approximately %5.3f.' % math.pi
```